# Split database into smaller ones. Too much data in single commit

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I need an advice :)

I have a database with almost 70 tables, many of them have over a dozen million big records. I want to split it into a few smaller ones. One for every big client data and one main database for the rest of the client's data(while also moving some of the data into NoSQL database). Because of many complicated relations between tables, before copying the data, I was disabling the triggers, that were checking the correctness of the foreign keys and then, just before a commit I was enabling them again.

It was all working with a small amount of data, but now, when I'm trying to copy one of the big client data I have a problem with the java heap size/GC out of memory.

I could increase the heap size, but it's not the point here.

I'm selecting data by some specific id from every table that has any relation to client data and copy it to another database. The process looks like this:

1. Select data from table
2. Insert data to another database
3. Copy sequence (max(id) of data being copied)
4. Flush/Clear
5. Repeat for every table containing client data

I was trying to select portions of data(something like select parts with 5000 rows instead of all 50 000 in one) but it fails in the exact same position.

And here I am asking for an advice, how to manage this problem. I think it is all because I am trying to copy all data in one big fatty commit. The reason of it is that I have to disable triggers while copying but also I must enable them before I can commit my changes.

Comment: "*I want to split it into a few smaller ones*" - why? A "dozen million" rows is not considered a large table nowadays. What do you think you gain from splitting the tables?

Comment: What is your main use case of these tables? a "dozen million" is not considered that much.

Comment: Main goal is that every of the "big" clients will have their own instance of application using their own instance of databse

Comment: You just want to copy data from one database to another? Have you considered another approach like foreign tables? It would be more direct. Is the database properly designed and normalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *When I'm trying to copy one of the big client data I have a problem with the java heap size/GC out of memory.*

Copying data should not be using the heap, so it seems you're not using cursor-based queries.

See "[Getting results based on a cursor](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor)" in the PostgreSQL JDBC documentation:

> **By default the driver collects all the results for the query at once**. This can be inconvenient for large data sets so the JDBC driver provides a means of basing a ResultSet on a database cursor and only fetching a small number of rows.
>
> A small number of rows are cached on the client side of the connection and when exhausted the next block of rows is retrieved by repositioning the cursor.
>
> [...]
>
> **Changing code to cursor mode is as simple as setting the fetch size of the Statement** to the appropriate size. Setting the fetch size back to 0 will cause all rows to be cached (the default behaviour).

So, add a `stmt.setFetchSize(1000)` *(or something like that)* to your code will ensure that the JDBC driver will not exhaust the heap.

If you still have trouble after that, then it's because *your* code is retaining all data, which means it's coded wrong for a copy operation.

Comment: Yea, you are right. With the second look it was just coded wrong. But as a quick solution I managed to do commit after every part of data (10k rows) instead of one big commit with everything. And after that I am enabling the triggers again. Users wont be using this database immediately so I guess it should be ok

Comment: @kamilke Doing commits more often will not help Java heap. It'll help keep database server transaction log size down, but has no effect on Java memory.